# I am facing an issue with app distribution as my app is set to 'private,'

Tags: ios, react-native

my app is in private in apple store

[image]

I am facing an issue with app distribution as my app is set to 'private,' and I do not have access to Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager.

How to make my app available on the Apple App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a private app to a public app.

If you want your app to be generally available on the App Store, you will need to create a new app record in App Store Connect with a unique bundle ID.  You can use the same code to build your app.

Add an additional target to your Xcode project with the new bundle ID and then add all of the existing source files to this target.

You can then archive and submit for review as normal.

Comment: Guideline 4.3 - Design
This app duplicates the content and functionality of other apps submitted by you or another developer to the App Store, which is considered a form of spam.
Apps that simply duplicate content or functionality create clutter, diminish the overall experience for the end user, and reduce the ability of developers to market their apps.
But i have already delete previous app form apple store connect .@Paulw11

Comment: I can't help.  You need to appeal to Apple; Explain that this app is replacing a previous private app.  Of course, if you have multiple apps in the App Store that are similar, but slightly different, say different branding, then Apple will reject you.